# Paypal Adaptive Payments in REST api

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Paypal Adaptive Payments in REST api without redirection to paypal is possible?

Already worked in, Redirect the payment sender's browser to https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=... after obtaining the pay key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**We can use Embedded Payment**

An embedded payment flow can be used for simple, parallel, and chained payments.

Embedded payment flow can be implemented in two ways

**lightbox option  and mini-browser option**

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc/